# Android error while starting application on startup

Tags: android, startup

I've made my application startup. I want it to start as soon as device opens. I wrote the codes that I need. It works. But, when device opens, it asks that **Complete action using: Launcher or My App**. However I don't want it. I want it to start on startup without asking the launcher. How can I do that? or can I set my app always default launcher in code? By the way, it gives this message: **Unfortunately, app finished..** on startup. *By the way, I may make mistakes while writing my codes. If there is an example, tutorial or expression about making Startup and Launcher, I can look at it.*

Answer (score 0):

1. No you can not set your App to default by code. The user has to decide, whether he wants your app to be default or any other app. This has been Android standard since the 1.0 release.
2. Your app finishes with an Exception? Please provide a Stacktrace of your crash.
3. Everybody makes mistakes. There are many tutorials out in the wild and quite a few questions here on Stackoverflow.